# How to access Firebase types without importing firebase module?

Tags: typescript, firebase

In my webapp I use Firebase from the CDN in order to limit the amount of data transfer from my account, as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#from-the-cdn). By using external scripts from the CDN, I do not have to bundle firebase module with my code, so my bundle is smaller.

Now my issue is that I would like to use the types provided by firebase when I write code for my webapp in typescript. How can I achieve that without importing the firebase module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution: I can import the firebase module, use it during typescript compilation, and finally exclude it from my bundle through [webpack externals config](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals):

In my html code:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.6/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.6/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

In my typescript code:

```
import firebase from "firebase";

firebase.initializeApp(...
```

In webpack.config.js:

```
externals: ["firebase"],
```

I have verified that my bundle is much slimmer: from 139kB to 53kB.

Comment: ii was using the same approach (externals in webpack conf) together CRA and Craco https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco but with no luck. I also tried to put index.d.ts from firebase to my dir and uninstall it firebase but then I still could not get it after TS transpilation...

Comment: Did you install firebase? ```npm i firebase``` Also I added ```"esModuleInterop": true``` in tsconfig.json